# Как определить, что грузит MySQL?

Tags: mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень часто пропадает коннект с БД из-за ее перегрузки.

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать, чтобы найти причину? Может, просто выявить наиболее "тяжелые" таблицы и проредить их? Как найти, обращение к каким таблицам, или выполнение каких операций провоцирует подобное?

Лимит ресурсов исчерпан.

Comment: Обычно у хостингов есть раздел "медленных" запросов. Если у вас свой сервер - тут вариантов очень много, некоторые из них: 1. в mysql есть встроенный функционал отслеживания медленных запросов https://habr.com/ru/post/31072/ 2. Если повезёт - в момент нагрузки высокой можно "застать" запрос который завис командой `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`

Comment: В статье есть строки: вызвать mysqld со следующими параметрами:  –log-slow-queries[=/tmp/slow_queries.log]. Как это может выглядеть в виде команды? Результат такой команды: "mysqld –log-slow-queries[=/tmp/slow_queries.log]" - "-bash: mysqld: команда не найдена"

Comment: Он выполняется в mysqld, если не знаете что это то лучше другим способом. 1. С помощью команды через SQL запрос `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%slow%';` можно посмотреть настройки логирования http://joxi.ru/gmvlWOOTqwBLkA пример. 2. Через запросы вида `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON'; FLUSH LOGS;` можно менять параметры эти.